# Gaussian Elimination with Matrices

Tags: gaussian-elimination

> Find the value of $k$ such that the following system of equations does not have a
>   unique solution: 
>   $$kx+y+2z = 4$$
>   $$-y+4z = 5$$
>   $$3x+4y+2z = 1$$

I am allowed to use a calculator.

The answer given is: 
[image]

Which I'm guessing has to do with matrices. Can anyone explain this?

Edit:

The answer given above is for a different question. My mistake. Here's the answer:[image]

Comment: Since the matrix' determinant is $-18k+18$, the answer is $k=1$.

Comment: For $k=5$, there is a unique solution: $x=1/2, y = -2/3, z = 13/12$.
For $k=1$ the system has no solutions. Something is wrong here.
Are you sure that the answer you showed us is the answer to that exercise?

Comment: @RobertZ Good catch. It is my mistake. The edit shows the correct answer. How do you get the determinant to equal $-18k+18$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$\det\left(\begin{vmatrix} k &1 & 2\\ 0 & -1 & 4\\ 3 & 4 & 2\end{vmatrix}\right)=(-2k +12+0) -(-6+16k+0)=18(1-k)$$
then the system has a unique solution iff  $k\not=1$. Moreover
$$\det\left(\begin{vmatrix} 1 &2 & 4\\ -1 & 4 & 5\\ 4 & 2 & 1\end{vmatrix}\right)=(4+40-8)-(64+10-2)-36\not = 0$$
therefore for $k=1$ the system has no solutions.

P.S. Remember that the system $Ax=b$ has at least a solution iff:
$rank(A)=rank(A∣b)$. In order to compute the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix I used [Sarrus Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

Comment: How did you calculate the determinant? I'm sorry for lacking such fundamentals.